# TFT5ForConditionalGeneration generate returns empty output_scores

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, encoder-decoder, text-generation

I'm fine-tuning the TFT5ForConditionalGeneration model ("t5-small"). Before doing model.fit() and save the model I set the `output_score=True` as well as the relevant parameters in the generation config. After fine-tuning the model I load it and I can see that in the loaded model the `config.output_scores = True` as well as the `generation_config.output_scores=True`.

However, when I generate the text, the `scores` returns empty.
How can I fix this please? I read documentation https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/internal/generation_utils#transformers.generation.TFSampleEncoderDecoderOutput, https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.36.1/en/main_classes/text_generation#transformers.TFGenerationMixin but wasn't able to figure out how to get the scores in the generated text.

I'm using  transformers version 4.36.0

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import json
import tensorflow as tf
from datasets import Dataset
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
from transformers import TFAutoModelForSeq2SeqLM, GenerationConfig, AutoConfig, AutoTokenizer, DataCollatorForSeq2Seq

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("t5-small", add_special_tokens=True, pad_to_max_length=True, truncation=True)


def tokenize_dataset(dataset):
    tokenized_dataset = dataset.map(
        tokenize, batched=True, num_proc=4, batch_size=16, remove_columns=['x', 'y'],
        fn_kwargs={
            "input_col": 'x', "output_col": 'y', "add_special_tokens": True, "pad_to_max_length": True, 
            "truncation": True, "max_input_length": 128, "tokenizer": tokenizer
        }
    )
    return tokenized_dataset


def tokenize(examples, input_col, output_col, add_special_tokens, pad_to_max_length, truncation, max_input_length, tokenizer):
    encodings = tokenizer(
        examples[input_col], add_special_tokens=add_special_tokens, pad_to_max_length=pad_to_max_length,
        truncation=truncation, max_length=max_input_length
    )

    with tokenizer.as_target_tokenizer():
        labels = tokenizer(
            examples[output_col], add_special_tokens=add_special_tokens, pad_to_max_length=pad_to_max_length,
            truncation=truncation, max_length=max_input_length
        )
    encodings["labels"] = labels["input_ids"]

    return encodings


def save_model(model, model_files_path, model_name):
    model_json = model.to_json()
    if not os.path.exists(model_files_path):
        os.makedirs(model_files_path)
    with open(os.path.join(model_files_path, model_name + ".json"), 'w') as json_file:
            json_file.write(model_json)
            json_file.close()

transformer_model_path = "<your path>"
model_files_path = "<your path>"
model_name = "model"
model_fn = model_name + ".h5"

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(os.path.join(model_files_path, model_fn), monitor="val_loss", verbose=1, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True, mode="min")
early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=4, min_delta=0.005, verbose=1)
callbacks = [early_stop, checkpoint]

train_df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['Mover, Part-time Afternoon Shift', 'Front Desk Clerk', 'Automotive Technician - $1,000 Sign-On Bonus', 'Administrative Manager', 'RN - Emergency Department', 'Port Operations Manager', 'Human Services Technician', 'Server administration', 'Wit & Wisdom-Food Runner', 'Business Development Executive', 'assistant', 'Technical Recruiter', 'Survey Research Technician III', 'Freelance- Translators/Linguists, English to Swedish (Swedish Native)', 'HR Technology Advisor'] * 4, 'y': ['Mover', 'Front Desk Clerk', 'Automotive Technician', 'Administrative Manager', 'RN - Emergency Department', 'Port Operations Manager', 'Human Services Technician', 'Server administration', 'Food Runner', 'Business Development Executive', 'assistant', 'Technical Recruiter', 'Survey Research Technician III', 'Translators/Linguists, English to Swedish', 'HR Technology Advisor'] * 4})
val_df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['Specialist, Client Success Management', 'Sales Engineer', 'REMOTE Data Engineer - Must Live in Midwest or East Coast!', 'API Developer', 'Accountant'] * 5, 'y': ['Specialist, Client Success Management', 'Sales Engineer', 'Data Engineer', 'API Developer', 'Accountant'] * 5})


train_dataset = Dataset.from_pandas(train_df)
val_dataset = Dataset.from_pandas(val_df)

tokenized_train_dataset = tokenize_dataset(train_dataset)
tokenized_val_dataset = tokenize_dataset(val_dataset)

config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained("t5-small")
config.output_scores = True
transformer_model = TFAutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("t5-small", config=config)

generation_config = GenerationConfig(**transformer_model.generation_config.__dict__)
generation_config.max_new_tokens = 10
generation_config.return_dict_in_generate = True
generation_config.output_scores = True

transformer_model.save_pretrained(transformer_model_path)
generation_config.save_pretrained(transformer_model_path)

data_collator = DataCollatorForSeq2Seq(tokenizer=tokenizer, model=transformer_model, return_tensors="tf")
train_dataset = tokenized_train_dataset.to_tf_dataset(batch_size=32, columns=["input_ids", "attention_mask", "labels"], shuffle=True, collate_fn=data_collator)
validation_dataset = tokenized_val_dataset.to_tf_dataset(batch_size=32, columns=["input_ids", "attention_mask", "labels"], shuffle=False, collate_fn=data_collator)

optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=2e-5)
transformer_model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, run_eagerly=True)
transformer_model.fit(train_dataset, validation_data=validation_dataset, epochs=2, callbacks=callbacks)

save_model(transformer_model, model_files_path, model_name)

# load model
transformer_model = TFAutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(transformer_model_path)
transformer_model.load_weights(os.path.join(model_files_path, model_fn))
generation_config = GenerationConfig.from_pretrained(transformer_model_path, "generation_config.json")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("t5-small")

text_lst = ["Mover, Part-time Afternoon Shift", "Front Desk Clerk"]
text_tokenized = tokenizer(text_lst, add_special_tokens=True, pad_to_max_length=True, truncation=True, max_length=True)

# text generation
# input_ids = [[283, 1890, 6, 2733, 18, 715, 621, 29, 32, 106, 4804, 89, 17, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
generated_text = transformer_model.generate(text_tokenized.input_ids, generation_config=generation_config, return_dict_in_generate=True, output_scores=True)
print(generated_text.scores)
```

**Edit Jan 9th 2023**

I added more information to the code above. I understand now why `generated_text.scores` was empty. When you run the above code the `generated_text.scores` is not empty. However, when I wrap the `transformer_model.generate()` within a function so I can use `jit_compile=True` it does return empty.

So now my question is how can I get the scores when using `jit_compile=True`?

```
@tf.function(jit_compile=True)
def generate(transformer_model, input_ids, generation_config):
    # https://github.com/huggingface/notebooks/blob/main/examples/translation-tf.ipynb
    generated_text = transformer_model.generate(
        input_ids, generation_config=generation_config, return_dict_in_generate=True, output_scores=True
    )

    return generated_text
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce this with your code. Transformers 4.36.1, tensorflow 2.15.0 returns a non-empty output for me: `>>> print(generated_text.scores)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 32128), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ -8.533397 ,  -3.8806133,  -9.9300785, ..., -34.75679  ,
        -34.75747  , -34.663628 ]], dtype=float32)>, ...`

Comment: @Daraan I updated the transformer version to 4.36.1 and the tensorflow version to 2.15.0, and indeed when I don't save the model I am able to get `>>> print(generated_text.scores)`. However when I save the model (like I did before the edit of my question) and then loaded again the `generated_text.scores` is an empty tuple. Any idea?

Comment: Is there still some code missing or can you add code that loads the model? Using the first code and also loading the config&model with the stored files still generates an output text for me.

Comment: @Daraan I added more code to get a working example as well as more information about the question.